# Kendo UI Grid RowTemplate with Action<T> parameter on Razor View Engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, delegates, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm tring to use Kendo UI Grid component and need to create my custom row template. Actually the gird is really awasome and usage is so cool. But some how I could'nt get display my custom  row template.

I need the whole model (I mean whole entity object to display aditional data but not display titles for them on column headers, like images of sub-itmes), so I'm trying to use `RowTemplate(System.Action<T>)` method that passes each entity for each row. For aspx pages, there is an example on their site as below:

```
<%= Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .RowTemplate(o =>
    {
%>
    <%= o.Name %>
    <%= o.Age %>
    <%
    })
    %>
```

But how to do this with razor? I couldn't get it. Should I use WriteLiteral or what? How to use `Action<T>` to display razor templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In razor you must use a [template delegate](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx):

```
.RowTemplate(@<text>
   <strong>@item.Name</strong>
   <span>@item.Age</span>
</text>);
```

Comment: Actually I've tried it. But when I use a foreach loop in the Func<T,object> template RowTemplate confuses about the template and behaves like RowTemplate(Action<T>) overriden one. Then I seperated the Func<T,object> to a different code block and passed it as a parameter to RowTemplate method. I've solved it like this.